# Node.js - MongoDB remove document doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to remove all documents from collection that have field called 
`uuid`and the value `$in` `array` that I pass. However, it doesn't work. Here is the code and the output that I have so far.

Code:

```
app.post("/deleteRetrievedOfflineMessages", function(req, res) {
    console.log("req.query.uuids => " + req.query.uuids);
    var uuids = [];
    uuids.push(req.query.uuids);
    console.log("uuids[] => " + uuids);

    offlineMessages.remove({ uuid: { $in: uuids } }, function(err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("offlineMessages.remove => no err");
            console.log("result => " + result);
            res.json("success");
        } else {
            sendErrorEmail(err);
            res.json("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Output:

```
req.query.uuids => b964ddaa52b24b6e9f06cc2d1269c064,e0262f6807b6445cb455ae99d90e0315,dc9760634f364bdaa963c46b9a95170b
uuids[] => b964ddaa52b24b6e9f06cc2d1269c064,e0262f6807b6445cb455ae99d90e0315,dc9760634f364bdaa963c46b9a95170b
offlineMessages.remove => no err
result => {"ok":1,"n":0}
```

Comment: `uuids` needs to be an array of ids. At the minute, you have an array which contains one item... a string of comma seperated uuids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split req.query.uuids before feeding it to the $in operator like so.

```
const uuids = req.query.uuids.split(',');
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just needed to add toString(), like this  - var uuids = req.query.uuids.toString().split(','); And now it works perfect.